# Service Fabric : Failed to configure certificate permissions - FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have installed all related certificates in my local system. But unable to figure-out why it is coming like this. Could you please help on this issue.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yzz9p.png)

Answer (score 1):

After spending lot of time to investigate, one of my certificate got expired. After installing new cert into my local system the error is no longer.

Comment: If you are facing this type issue with Service Fabric please do see first in Event Viewer there you can find exact details regarding issue.